# Emacs WinDbg kernel mode

Tags: emacs, windbg, kernel-mode

I'm using WinDbg for kernel mode debugging and I'd like to use the emacs interface to WinDbg. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cdb-gud.el. But cdb-gud.el only shows how to use Emacs with WinDbg for debugging user programs.

Does anybody know how to use Emacs with WinDbg for kernel mode debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `kd -k <connection string>` instead of `cdb <your program>` e.g. M-x cdb  `kd -k com:port=com1`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see the source-code and stack in speedbar you can use my hacked version of cdb-gud
https://github.com/4DA/kd-gud